# separate front-end app and back-end app on two different servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, frontend, backend

I have a question about separating front-end app and back-end app on two different servers.

Front-end: AngularJS, make $http API calls, hosted on Tomcat, ip: 1.1.1.1

Back-end: Ruby on Rails, hosted on Nginx, ip: 2.2.2.2

I want to restrict Ruby on Rails to receive requests from 1.1.1.1, how can I do that?

I find that since AngularJS web app is on browser client side, if I set on Ngnix.conf to allow access from 1.1.1.1, it won't work.

Comment: Why do you think that restricting your rails server is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to restrict Ruby on Rails to receive requests from 1.1.1.1, how can I do that?

**Thats a really bad idea.** It would require your frontend server to proxy every request to the backend. This would have significant overhead - and no real benefits.

If you are proxying you can no longer run the frontend server as a lean-mean static-file delivery machine which is what the frontend server in a SPA really should do.

Proxying requests from clients so that they appear to originate from your own server opens a pandoras box of security issues.

Therefore the backend server MUST be open to and respond directly to clients. Thats what an API server does after all!

Comment: Proxying is what we HAD to do back in the days of JSONP to circumvent the same origin policy. The security implications of having a clients request appear as it came from your own server are very bad.